# What app does macOS Mojave use for screen recording?

Tags: quicktime, mojave, screen-recording

I just upgraded to macOS Mojave on Macbook Air. I press command + shift + 5 on keyboard, it prompts a window where I select part of screen and then I begin recording my screen. The video quality is good and even the default microphone works well.

However, it is a little mysterious to me what program it is using for this. In the past, it would use QuickTime. However, I do not see QuickTime or any menu bar visible when this screen sharing utility launches. Also, after I save, and open it, it suggests to open in Quicktime.

Is it using QuickTime behind the scenes, albeit without a menu bar?

Comment: when you play it who does it

Comment: @Buscar웃 it gives me a list of options and I use Quicktime. That is, after it is saved. If you have Mojave, you can see exactly what I am talking about by pressing command + shift + 5 on computer.

Comment: I do not have Mojave at this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start screen recording then open the activity monitor.
You will see a process name screencapture.
Click process info botton will see more detail.
It seems like a system level functions and use intel quick sync to encode.
[image: screencapture]

Comment: The tool is called "Screenshot" and it is an App that is bundled with macOS and can be found in the *Utilities* folder.  The shortcut keys are set by default to launch the App.

Comment: @Allan You're right, but /usr/sbin/screencapture is the background process that did the actual recording work.

Comment: They are one in the same; there's no different process and is most definitely not a "system level" (which denotes something that happens at the kernel level) process.